# TabView in Toolbar in swift

Tags: macos, swift, nstoolbar, nstabview

Can I create a tab view in toolbar like the app Photos (Yosemite)? I want only a segmented buttons, without images.
I have tried to set the style of TabView Controller into 'Toolbar', but it creates also images.

Comment: @ChrisSlowik It's a question about OS X not iOS.

Comment: Im embarrassed - my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `NSSegmentedControl` for that. That will give you the buttons without the tab view